# how to use jndi in shiro?

Tags: spring-boot, jndi, shiro

this is springboot with jndi

```
@Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat) {
                tomcat.enableNaming();//启用默认禁用的JNDI命名
                return super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
            }
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {

                List<DataConfig>  list =  dataConfigProperty.getDatabase();
                for (DataConfig dataConfig : list) {
                    //构建一个ContextResource对象，然后添加到Context对象中
                    ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
                    resource.setName(dataConfig.getJndiname());
                    resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
                    resource.setProperty("driverClassName", dataConfig.getDriverClassName());
                    resource.setProperty("url", dataConfig.getUrl());
                    resource.setProperty("username", dataConfig.getUsername());
                    resource.setProperty("password",dataConfig.getPassword());
                    context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
                }

                super.postProcessContext(context);
            }
        };
        return tomcat;
    }
```

But this loading order is after shiro loading。
Please give me some suggestions. Thank you

I don't know how to solve it